# Not able to update data in one-to-one relation in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am trying to update my `productDetails` table and `productMaster` table.

Here is my relation:

ProductMaster.ts:

```
@OneToOne(type => ProductDetails, productDetails => productDetails.productMaster,{
    cascade: ["insert", "update"]
})
productDetails: ProductDetails;
```

ProductDetails.ts:

```
@OneToOne(type => ProductMaster,  productMaster => productMaster.productDetails,{
    cascade: ["insert", "update"]
})
@JoinColumn({name: 'prd_id', referencedColumnName: 'prd_id'})
productMaster: ProductMaster;
```

Now I have to update my `productMaster` and `productDetails` using TypeORM relations.

Here is what I tried:

```
productMasterRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .update()
        .set({
           prd_name : 'my Product Name'
           productDetails : {
               prd_brand : 'My Product Brand Name'
           }
          })
        .where("prd_id = :prd_id", {prd_id: 1})
        .execute();
```

But it doesn't update.

Comment: Hi Can you please share complete model for both ProductMaster and ProductDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem here is you want to join the tables and update them both at the same time it will use joins, but it is not possible to create complex queries like this.

Typeorm only supports `joins` on the select expression

refer to this [Refer This](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/564)

It is only possible using `raw queries`